# Issue with first element (classList.contains)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to listen if an element contains a specific class. That's works actually pretty good, but not for the first item element. After I have slide a item and produce a click, I get on all elements, `false` back in the console.log , except in the first element, it is always `true`. I do expect a "false" to use the function for further actions. I have no idea, why always the first item returns a "true". It's a weird phenomenon.

```
 <ion-list>
            <ion-item-sliding #slideItem *ngFor="let user of users">
            <ion-item>{{ user }}  </ion-item>


            <ion-item-options side="left">
              <button ion-button (click)="delete(user)">Delete</button>
            </ion-item-options>

          </ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-list>
```

**TS**

```
  @ViewChild('slideItem', {read: ElementRef}) slideItem : ElementRef;

  users = ['Paul', 'Lisa', 'Max', "Bernd"]

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickHandler(event) {

      console.log(this.slideItem.nativeElement.classList.contains('active-slide'));

    }
```

Comment: maybe because it always has `active-slide` class?

Comment: Nope, the class gets removed after click. It has the same behavor as the other item elements.

Comment: try `setTimeout(()=>console.log(this.slideItem.nativeElement.classList.contains('active-slide')))`, let me know what you get then